# Move two buttons in one range and display them next to each other

Tags: excel, vba

I have two `buttons` in my spreadsheet and I use the following VBA to move both buttons into `Range("D12:D12")`:

```
Sub Move_Buttons()

Set Range_01 = Sheet1.Range("D12:D12")
With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1")
.Top = Range_01.Top
.Left = Range_01.Left
.Width = Range_01.Width
.Height = Range_01.Height
End With

Set Range_02 = Sheet1.Range("D12:D12")
With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 2")
.Top = Range_02.Top
.Left = Range_02.Left
.Width = Range_02.Width
.Height = Range_02.Height
End With

End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

As you can see in my code the two buttons are both moved into `Range("D12:D12")` so they are lying on top of each other within this cell. 
Now, I am wondering if there is a way to put both buttons next to each other within the `Range("D12:D12")` so the user is still able to see both of them?

I know I could sove the issue by 
a)  putting one of the buttons into `Range("E12:E12")` 
b)  manually assinging a `.Top Left .Width .Height` condition to it

However, I would prefer a flexible solution in which the buttons both stay in `Range("D12:D12")` but with a `.Width` of `50/50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would prefer a flexible solution in which the buttons both stay in Range("D12:D12") but with a .Width of 50/50.

**Logic**

1. The `Width` of both buttons becomes half.
2. The placement of the 2nd Button will be after the first button. `Left` of Button1 + `Width` of Button1.

**Code**

Is this what you are trying? Also since you are dealing with the same range then you do not need to `Range_01` and `Range_02`. One will do.

```
Sub Move_Buttons()
    Dim Range_01 As Range

    Set Range_01 = Sheet1.Range("D12:D12")

    With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1")
        .Top = Range_01.Top
        .Left = Range_01.Left
        .Width = Range_01.Width / 2 '<~~ This becomes half
        .Height = Range_01.Height
    End With

    With Sheet1.Buttons("Button 2")
        .Top = Range_01.Top
        '~~> And this changes as mentioned above in the LOGIC section
        .Left = Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1").Left + Sheet1.Buttons("Button 1").Width
        .Width = Range_01.Width / 2 '<~~ This becomes half
        .Height = Range_01.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Awesome. Thanks a lot.